# Is it possible to control the order .CSS files are read by Rails or is it fixed by convention?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, view

In my Rails project I have 3 .css files:

> application.css
>
> bootstrap.css
>
> todo.scss

If I wanted to add another .css library is there a way of controlling the order the .css files are read when `.require_tree` is called in `application.css`.

Also how does Rails know to load load `bootstrap.css` before `todo.scss` so that bootstrap does not overide the specific View scope styling in `todo.scss`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 Load css in particular order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890929/rails-3-1-load-css-in-particular-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SCSS**

I believe the [`require_tree`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) directive loads the files in alphabetical order

If you want to load the files in your own order, you may be interested in looking into using the [`@import` functionality of `scss`](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) (the Rails default CSS [preprocessor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing))

You'll be able to do the following:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import bootstrap
@import todo
@import **/* /* Directory Globbing ;-) */
```

--

This will allow you to load the individual files / directories you require in the order you require